# Tracking banners from internal subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have the website: example.com which is displaying internal banners hosted on ads.example.com.

I've tried to implement `utm` tags to the destination URLs but that screws up my data because it overwrites the original `source/medium/campaign` attributes of the user.

So now I'm looking for a way to effectively monitor the impressions & clicks of these ads in analytics without overwriting the analytics cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Event Tracking code its easy and good to track without manipulating your source medium data. Here is the sample code:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner-name', 'size', 'ad-content'])"
```